# How much is the departure tax when leaving Cartagena, Colombia by air? (CTG)

Tags: airports, import-taxes, colombia

How much is the departure tax to pay when leaving Cartagena, Colombia by air if you are a tourist?

I've read online that in Bogota, there is a desk you can stop at in the airport if you are a tourist and show your airline receipt.  They'll note the tax and give you a special piece of paper with a stamp that says you do not have to pay it, since it's already been paid when paying for your plane ticket.

I've also read that there's a similar desk in the Cartagena airport (CTG), but there are no details as to where it is, expected wait times, etc.

I've also heard that departure taxes have changed for 2015.

Does anyone have any details on the current taxes, procedures at the CTG airport, and expected wait times for different times of the day?

Comment: If there's a desk for this, it's very likely that some tickets do not have departure tax included.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Columbuese airports association](http://www.sacsa.co/?lang=es&opc=4&sel=1):

[image]

The tax for **domestic** flights is 19`USD`. The tax for **international** flights is 39`USD`. Whether or not it's included in your ticket depends on the airline.

Answer (score 1):

In most airlines, the tax is included in the ticket, I never had to pay the tax after 2008.